# Acorrect range of concentrations for the reactants in the equilibrium reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium, concentration, spectrophotometry

> What would be a correct range of concentrations for the reactants in the equilibrium reaction, $\ce{Fe^3+(aq) + SCN-(aq) <=> FeSCN^2+}$?

For a Chemistry project I am measuring the effects of changing the concentration of $\ce{Fe^3+(aq)}$ on the yield of $\ce{FeSCN^2+(aq)}$ produced. I'm going to use a spectrophotometer to calculate the absorbance of the products.

I was wondering what amounts of concentrations of $\ce{Fe^3+(aq)}$ and $\ce{SCN-(aq)}$ would be suitable.

My research suggests that I should set the spectrophotometer to around $\pu{450 nm }$and that the domain of the concentration of the product $\ce{FeSCN^2+(aq)}$ should be between $0 \le [\ce{FeSCN^2+(aq)}] \le 2 \times 10^{-4}$. Since I don't know the equilibrium constant, I would need to look at literature to find out what concentrations would be ideal since when absorbance > 1, the relationship is no longer linear.

I'm only varying the concentration of $\ce{Fe^3+(aq)}$ in 10 intervals (currently $\pu{0.1-1 mol/dl^3}$), the concentration of the $\ce{SCN-(aq)}$ will be kept constant.

What would be the ideal concentration range for $\ce{Fe^3+(aq)}$ and the ideal concentration for $\ce{SCN-(aq)}$?

ps. I am adding $\ce{HCl}$ as a neutralizer to the $\ce{Fe(OH)-}$ formed since it distorts the colour of the solution.
I am also using $\pu{20 ml}$ of $\ce{Fe^3+(aq)}$ solution and $\pu{20 ml}$ of $\ce{SCN-(aq)}$ and $\pu{10 ml}$ of $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: Is not 0.1-1 M Fe^3+ too much ? Absorbance would be IMHO out of range. The reaction is very sensitive, used to quantitative Fe determination. So, rather consider [Fe^3+] the same as the final [FeSCN^2+]

Comment: Why do you think that the absorbance is not linear when it is less than 1 ? Linearity goes from absorbance of 0 to approx 2.5 the upper value being limited by the quality of the instrument used and not for any fundamental reason based on Beer-Lambert law. From memory the FeSCN has a max extinction coefficient of approx 450 $\mathrm{dm^3\,mol^{-1}\,cm^{-1}}$ so you will need dilute solutions in the range you give.

Comment: @porphyrin, I made a typo, it should be A > 1. My teacher recommended that I try to measure values of absorbance less than 1.